# Sending a form to email not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a form that will be sent to my email. But it display errors on submission. Javascript to validate the form is not shown but it works fine.
I am not sure what's wrong with my code below, been trying to figure out all day and reading various threads but to no avail.

Below is my php code to handle the form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "me@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Nexwave Form";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email']; // not required
$users = $_POST['users']; // required

$error_message = "";
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Designation: ".clean_string($designation)."\n";
$email_message .= "company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
$email_message .= "Contact ".clean_string($contact)."\n";
$email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Number of Users: ".clean_string($users)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
echo (int) mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Below is my html code:

```
<form name="form" action="send_mail.php" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST">
&nbsp;Name<br/><input name="name" type="text" style="width:90%;"/><br/>
&nbsp;Designation<br/><input name="designation" type="text" style="width:90%;"/><br/>
&nbsp;Company<br/><input name="company" type="text"  style="width:90%;"/><br/>
&nbsp;Contact Number<br/><input name="contact" type="text" style="width:90%;"/><br/>
&nbsp;Email<br/><input name="email" type="text" style="width:90%;"/><br/>
&nbsp;Number of Users<br/><input name="users" type="text" style="width:90%;"/>
<span style="text-align:right;display:block;width:174px;"><input style="height:25px;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:#ffffff;border:0;color:#009110;" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" /></span>
</form>
```

below is the error:
This is what i get even after changing the email_address and email_from.

```
"; echo $error."

"; echo "Please go back and fix these errors.

"; die(); } $name = $_POST['name']; // required $designation = $_POST['designation']; $company = $_POST['company']; $contact = $_POST['contact']; $email = $_POST['email']; // not required $users = $_POST['users']; // required $error_message = ""; $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n"; function clean_string($string) { $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); return str_replace($bad,"",$string); } $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; $email_message .= "Designation: ".clean_string($designation)."\n"; $email_message .= "company: ".clean_string($company)."\n"; $email_message .= "Contact ".clean_string($contact)."\n"; $email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n"; $email_message .= "Number of Users: ".clean_string($users)."\n"; // create email headers $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); echo (int) mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); ?> Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```

your help is very much appreciated

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? `mail()` is returning false? It's outputting an error message? Sending blank emails? Sending emails to the wrong address? Sending emails you're not getting?

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: `input name="email_address"` `$email = $_POST['email'];` what's going on

Comment: hi,sorry did not specify that clearly,
Upon submission of the form , all i get is error like "please fix this error + bunch of my php code", no email sent either

Comment: @user2106416 - adding the error you're getting to the question will help no end.

Comment: @DaveChen - additionally `$email_from` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @DaveChen , fixed it still the same error displayed

Comment: haha just noticed that too, maybe it's defined globally?

Comment: fixed everything about the $email_from the email_address .

It still outputs the same page which is :
    
"; echo $error."

"; echo "Please go back and fix these errors.
"; die(); } $name = $_POST['name']; // required $designation =......

Comment: @user2106416 - are you using PHP short tags, perchance? If you are, please switch them to the longer tags instead.

Comment: i used the longer tags, i.e. <?php ?>

Comment: @user2106416 - interesting; that error message implies that you're opening a tag for your PHP code, but it's not being interpreted as PHP for some reason - that's why the output starts immediately after the first `>` in your echo. Could you edit your question and add the whole PHP file in?

Comment: @andrewsi there you go. thanks

Comment: @user2106416 - well, that's odd. For one thing, you're not actually calling that `died()` function anywhere. Are you sure your webserver is set up to process PHP files - what do you get if you go straight to send_mail.php in your browser?

Comment: @andrewsi hmm, when i open it in my browser, it gives the same error. Sorry im kinda new to php and web development. Currently im just opening it in my local host

Comment: @user2106416 - You are running it though a webserver, aren't you?

Comment: currently im just opening it in my computer, double click on my html files(same directory as the send_mail.php file), filling in the form and submit. and i got that message.

Comment: @user2106416 - that's the issue. PHP needs to be compiled for it to work, and just opening the file like that won't work. You need to install a web server on your computer, and access it that way.

Comment: @andrewsi , yeah just ran it on my xampp, it works! thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors present in this script as mentioned by question comments above.

- email form name `email_address` is not the same as `$_POST['email']`
- you are not defining `$email_from` before you call it.

I would do some simple testing before posting a question like this and try to echo out all the variables one by one and see what you get. This would show you the two mentioned errors. And if you cannot solve it and still have errors then please post your error message so others can be of more assistance than just it doesn't work.